# Generators of $Sp(2n)$

Tags: group-theory, matrices, symplectic-geometry

Let $\sigma =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Define  $J_{2n} = \underbrace{\sigma \oplus \cdots \oplus \sigma}_{\text{$n$ copy}}$. We define a $2n \times 2n$ real matrix matrix $A$ as symplectic if $AJ_{2n}A^T=J_{2n}$, where $T$ is the transpose operation. I want to prove/disprove the following statement.

$Sp(2n)$ is generated by $4 \times 4$ symplectic matrices. (More explicitly, it is by matrices of the type $S$, where $X\in Sp(4)$ is a principal sub-minor, and identity on the complementary  space).

Comment: Can we use the corresponding Lie algebra in the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sketch of a proof that I think *should* work:

Note that $\mathfrak{sp}(2n)$ can be defined by
$$
X \in \mathfrak{sp}(2n) \iff e^{tX} \in Sp(2n) \quad \forall t \in \Bbb R
$$
and given by the set of $X$ satisfying
$$
J_{2n} X^T J_{2n} = X
$$
this is a linear vector space.  Verify that we can make a basis for this space out of the otherwise zero matrices with a principle subminor that meets this requirement.

It is a theorem that for Lie group $G$ with algebra $\mathfrak g$, the matrices $e^X$ with $X \in \mathfrak g$ generate $G$.  It follows (?) that the matrices $e^X$ with $X$ in our basis generate $G$.